# CSS images using percents for size in table are all on top of each other

Tags: html, css, image-resizing

Okay so I have been redeveloping my website trying to make it look more professional and everything I know I have taught myself using online resources. I have hit a bump in the road though so here is my problem. (please be a bit forging if it is something very obvious. I am only 14 and have only been coding in HTML and CSS for about a year.)

My website is for my LEGO Stop-motion videos (my other hobby besides coding) and I want to make it so all my movie posters are like in a collage. I have succeed in doing this but it is using exact width and height in px.
Here is the html

```
<body>

 <!-- title div -->       
 <div id="head">

     <img src=pic/title.png alt="title" class="M35F">

 </div>

 <!-- menu bar line -->
 <div id="line" style="text-size: 2px;">

     <img class='menu home' src=pic/home.png alt="Home" onclick="window.location='index.html';">
          <img class="blank" src=pic/blank.png alt="b">

     <img class='menu about' src=pic/about.jpg alt="About" onclick="window.location='About.html';">
          <img class="blank" src=pic/blank.png alt="b">

     <img class='menu comment' src=pic/comment.jpg alt="Comments" onclick="window.location='Comments.html';">
          <img class="blank" src=pic/blank.png alt="b">

     <img class='menu pic' src=pic/pic.png alt="Pictures" onclick="window.location='Pictures.html';"> 
          <img class="blank" src=pic/blank.png alt="b">

     <img class='menu active' src=pic/active.png alt="Activities" onclick="window.location='games.html';">
          <img class="blank" src=pic/blank.png alt="b">

 </div>


 <!-- Explanation area -->
 <br>
 <br> my website is a collection of stop-motion animated videos. 
 <br>To learn more check out the About Page.
 <br>Just click on the movie poster to go to that movies page where you can watch it.      


 <!-- main div section with the posters -->
 <div style="margin-left:0%; margin-right:0%; width:100%; text-align:center;font-size: 25px">

     <br>
     <br>
     <table class="table">
        <!-- MKI6 and The Coffee Break -->
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="posterEffect1">
                <img class="bottom poster1" src=pic/blur/tcb.png alt="The Coffee Break" />
                <img class="top poster1" src=pic/tcb.png alt="The Coffee Break" />
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
             <div class="posterEffect1">
                <img class="bottom poster1" src=pic/blur/MKI6.png alt="MKI6" />
                <img class="top poster1" src=pic/MKI6.png alt="MKI6" />
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>  

        <!-- The Vehicle Show Race. The Prodigal Son-->
        <tr>  
          <td style="font-size: 5px;">
             <div class="posterEffect1">
                <img class="bottom poster1" src=pic/blur/tvsr.png alt="The Vehicle Show Race">
                <img class="top poster1" src=pic/tvsr.png alt="tvsr" />
             </div>
          </td>

          <td style="font-size: 5px;" rowspan="2">
            <div class="posterEffect">
              <img class="bottom poster" src=pic/blur/TPSPoster.png alt="tps">
              <img class="top poster" src=pic/TPSPoster.png alt="tps">
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <!-- Lt. James -->
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2">
            <div class="posterEffect">
               <img class="bottom poster" src=pic/blur/lt.james.png alt="Lt. James">
               <img class="top poster" src=pic/lt.james.png alt="Lt. James">
            </div> 
          </td>             
        </tr> 

        <!-- The a-g attack -->
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="posterEffect1">
              <img class="bottom poster1" src=pic/blur/ag.jpg alt="The Air-to-Ground Attack">                
              <img class="top poster1" src=pic/ag.jpg alt="The Air-to-Ground Attack">
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr> 

        <!-- The robbers race and the counterfeiters --> 
        <tr>
          <td> 
             <div class="posterEffect">
                <img class="bottom poster" src=pic/blur/TRR.jpg alt="The robbers race">
                <img class="top poster" src=pic/TRR.jpg alt="The robbers race">
             </div> 
          </td>
          <td>   
             <div class="posterEffect">
                <img class="bottom poster" src=pic/blur/tcp.jpg alt="The Counterfeiters">
                <img class="top poster" src=pic/tcp.jpg alt="The Counterfeiters">
             </div> 
          </td>
       </tr>

        <!-- The French plane  -->
       <tr>
          <td> 
             <div class="posterEffect">
                <img class="bottom poster" src=pic/blur/TFP.jpg alt="The French Plane">
                <img class="top poster" src=pic/TFP.jpg alt="The French Plane">
             </div> 
          </td>
          <td>   
             <div class="posterEffect">
                <img class="bottom poster" src=pic/blur/pic.jpg alt="pic">
                <img class="top poster" src=pic.jpg alt="pic">
             </div> 
          </td>
       </tr>

     </table>       
     <br> 
     <br> 
     <br> 
     <br> 
     <br> 
     <br> 
     <br> 
     <br> 

     <br>
     <br> 
     <br> 
     <br> 
     <br> 
     <br>  


     <!-- footer credits -->
     <div style="width:100%; text-align:center; font-size: 25px;">
        <br>
        <footer style="text-align:left; background-color:#FFFFFF; color:#888888; font-size: 25px">LEGO, the LEGO logo, and the Minifigure are trademarks and/or copyrights of the LEGO Group. I am not supported by LEGO or in any way is this website. Check out the LEGO website for more cool stuff. <a href="Link I can't post because I don't have enough Privilege">LEGO.com</a> 
           <br>
           <br>
        </footer>
     </div>
```

And here is the CSS

```
/* makes sure that the website title is not to big */ 
.M35F {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 905px; 
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* makes sure the buttons are not to big */
.home {
    width: 10.1%;
    max-width: 107px;  
}

.about {
    width: 11.1%;
    max-width: 117px;  
}

.comment {
    width: 16.7%;
    max-width: 173px;  
}

.pic {
    width: 16.8%;
    max-width: 174px;  
}

.active {
    width: 16.1%;
    max-width: 167px;  
}

.blank {
    width: 1%;
    max-width: 3px;
    max-height: 25px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}


/* makes the margin for the menu buttons */
.menu {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-filter 0.5s; /* Safari */
    -moz-transition: -webkit-filter 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: -webkit-filter 0.5s;
    -o-transition: -webkit-filter 0.5s;
    transition: -webkit-filter 0.5s;;

}

.menu:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    -webkit-filter: invert(1); /* Safari */
    -moz-filter: invert(1);
    -ms-filter: invert(1);
    -o-filter: invert(1);
    filter: invert(1);

}
/* makes sure links never get underlined */
a {
    text-decoration:none;
}



/* makes the  stuff for the tall posters */
.poster {
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     border-radius: 15px;
     max-width: 450px;
     max-height: 601px;
}

.posterEffect {
     position: relative;
     width: 450px;
     height: 601px;
}


.posterEffect img {
     position:absolute;
     left:0;
     -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
     transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.posterEffect img.top:hover {
  opacity:0;
}

.posterEffect:hover {
  transform:scale(1.02,1.02);
}


/* makes the  stuff for the wide posters */
.poster1 {
     width: 100%;
     border-radius: 15px;
     max-width: 450px;
     max-height: 260px;
}




.posterEffect1 {
     position: relative;
     width: 450px;
     height: 260px;
}


.posterEffect1 img { 
     position:absolute;
     left:0;
     -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
     transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.posterEffect1 img.top:hover {
  opacity:0;
}

.posterEffect1:hover {
  transform:scale(1.02,1.02);
}












/* the main table holder for the posters */
.table {
     width: 100%;
     max-width: 900px;
     border: 0px solid black;
     text-align:center; 
     margin-left:auto; 
     margin-right:auto; 
     border-spacing: 4px;
}

/* sets the body properties */
body {
    background-image:url('pic/lego.jpeg');
    background-color: #ffd700;
    text-align:center; 
    font-size: 25px;
}


/* the title attributes */ 
body{margin:0;padding:0}
#head {
    background-image:url('pic/lego1.jpeg');
    background-repeat:repeat;
    width: 100%;
}

/*the menu line div attributes */
body{margin:0;padding:0}  
#line {
    background-image:url('pic/line.jpeg');
    background-repeat:repeat;
    width: 100%;

}
```

The problem with this is that if you look at it on a mobile device the posters will spill of onto the right side of the screen and won't get smaller. 
I then tried to make it so that the images will get smaller with the browser window. I have been able to do this before fine using percents and max-width to make sure it doesn't get to big like this

```
.imgResizer {
     width: 50%;
     max-width: 350px; /*the images full width*/
}
```

but no matter what I tried when I did this with the pictures in the table I could get it to work right. I have made the images be able to re size with the window but they are all on top of each other. 
Here is an image to show what I mean.
[Pictures overlaying each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmwnn.jpg)

Here is my html

```
  <body>

 <!-- title div -->       
 <div id="head">

     <img src=pic/title.png alt="title" class="M35F">

 </div>

 <!-- menu bar line -->
 <div id="line" style="text-size: 2px;">

     <img class='menu home' src=pic/home.png alt="Home" onclick="window.location='index.html';">
          <img class="blank" src=pic/blank.png alt="b">

     <img class='menu about' src=pic/about.jpg alt="About" onclick="window.location='About.html';">
          <img class="blank" src=pic/blank.png alt="b">

     <img class='menu comment' src=pic/comment.jpg alt="Comments" onclick="window.location='Comments.html';">
          <img class="blank" src=pic/blank.png alt="b">

     <img class='menu pic' src=pic/pic.png alt="Pictures" onclick="window.location='Pictures.html';"> 
          <img class="blank" src=pic/blank.png alt="b">

     <img class='menu active' src=pic/active.png alt="Activities" onclick="window.location='games.html';">
          <img class="blank" src=pic/blank.png alt="b">

 </div>


 <!-- Explanation area -->
 <br>
 <br> is a collection of stop-motion animated videos. 
 <br>To learn more about check out the About Page.
 <br>Just click on the movie poster to go to that movies page where you can watch it.      


 <!-- main div section with the posters -->
 <div style="margin-left:0%; margin-right:0%; width:100%; text-align:center;font-size: 25px">

     <br>
     <br>
     <table class="table">
        <!-- MKI6 and The Coffee Break -->
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="posterEffect1">
                <img class="bottom poster1" src=pic/blur/tcb.png alt="The Coffee Break" />
                <img class="top poster1" src=pic/tcb.png alt="The Coffee Break" />
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
             <div class="posterEffect1">
                <img class="bottom poster1" src=pic/blur/MKI6.png alt="MKI6" />
                <img class="top poster1" src=pic/MKI6.png alt="MKI6" />
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>  

        <!-- The Vehicle Show Race. The Prodigal Son-->
        <tr>  
          <td style="font-size: 5px;">
             <div class="posterEffect1">
                <img class="bottom poster1" src=pic/blur/tvsr.png alt="The Vehicle Show Race">
                <img class="top poster1" src=pic/tvsr.png alt="tvsr" />
             </div>
          </td>

          <td style="font-size: 5px;" rowspan="2">
            <div class="posterEffect">
              <img class="bottom poster" src=pic/blur/TPSPoster.png alt="tps">
              <img class="top poster" src=pic/TPSPoster.png alt="tps">
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <!-- Lt. James -->
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2">
            <div class="posterEffect">
               <img class="bottom poster" src=pic/blur/lt.james.png alt="Lt. James">
               <img class="top poster" src=pic/lt.james.png alt="Lt. James">
            </div> 
          </td>             
        </tr> 

        <!-- The a-g attack -->
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="posterEffect1">
              <img class="bottom poster1" src=pic/blur/ag.jpg alt="The Air-to-Ground Attack">                
              <img class="top poster1" src=pic/ag.jpg alt="The Air-to-Ground Attack">
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr> 

        <!-- The robbers race and the counterfeiters --> 
        <tr>
          <td> 
             <div class="posterEffect">
                <img class="bottom poster" src=pic/blur/TRR.jpg alt="The robbers race">
                <img class="top poster" src=pic/TRR.jpg alt="The robbers race">
             </div> 
          </td>
          <td>   
             <div class="posterEffect">
                <img class="bottom poster" src=pic/blur/tcp.jpg alt="The Counterfeiters">
                <img class="top poster" src=pic/tcp.jpg alt="The Counterfeiters">
             </div> 
          </td>
       </tr>

        <!-- The French plane -->
       <tr>
          <td> 
             <div class="posterEffect">
                <img class="bottom poster" src=pic/blur/TFP.jpg alt="The French Plane">
                <img class="top poster" src=pic/TFP.jpg alt="The French Plane">
             </div> 
          </td>
          <td>   
             <div class="posterEffect">
                <img class="bottom poster" src=pic/blurs.jpg alt="pic">
                <img class="top poster" src=pic/clear.jpg alt="pic">
             </div> 
          </td>
       </tr>

     </table>       
     <br> 
     <br> 
     <br> 
     <br> 
     <br> 
     <br> 
     <br> 
     <br> 

     <br>
     <br> 
     <br> 
     <br> 
     <br> 
     <br>  


     <!-- footer credits -->
     <div style="width:100%; text-align:center; font-size: 25px;">
        <br>
        <footer style="text-align:left; background-color:#FFFFFF; color:#888888; font-size: 25px">LEGO, the LEGO logo, and the Minifigure are trademarks and/or copyrights of the LEGO Group. I am not supported by LEGO or in any way is this website. Check out the LEGO website for more cool stuff. <a href="link that I can't post because I don't have enough reputaion">LEGO.com</a> 
           <br>
           <br>
        </footer>
     </div>
```

And my css

```
    /* makes sure that the website title is not to big */ 
.M35F {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 905px; 
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* makes sure the buttons are not to big */
.home {
    width: 10.1%;
    max-width: 107px;  
}

.about {
    width: 11.1%;
    max-width: 117px;  
}

.comment {
    width: 16.7%;
    max-width: 173px;  
}

.pic {
    width: 16.8%;
    max-width: 174px;  
}

.active {
    width: 16.1%;
    max-width: 167px;  
}

.blank {
    width: 1%;
    max-width: 3px;
    max-height: 25px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}


/* makes the margin for the menu buttons */
.menu {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-filter 0.5s; /* Safari */
    -moz-transition: -webkit-filter 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: -webkit-filter 0.5s;
    -o-transition: -webkit-filter 0.5s;
    transition: -webkit-filter 0.5s;;

}

.menu:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    -webkit-filter: invert(1); /* Safari */
    -moz-filter: invert(1);
    -ms-filter: invert(1);
    -o-filter: invert(1);
    filter: invert(1);

}
/* makes sure links never get underlined */
a {
    text-decoration:none;
}



/* makes the  stuff for the tall posters */
.poster {
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     border-radius: 15px;
     max-width: 450px;
     max-height: 601px;
}

.posterEffect {
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     height: 135.55%;
     max-width: 450px;
     max-height: 601px;
}


.posterEffect img {
     position:absolute;
     left:0;
     -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
     transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.posterEffect img.top:hover {
  opacity:0;
}

.posterEffect:hover {
  transform:scale(1.02,1.02);
}


/* makes the  stuff for the wide posters */
.poster1 {
     width: 100%;
     border-radius: 15px;
     max-width: 450px;
     max-height: 260px;
}




.posterEffect1 {
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     height: 57.78%;
     max-width: 450px;
     max-height: 260px;
}


.posterEffect1 img { 
     position:absolute;
     left:0;
     -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
     transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.posterEffect1 img.top:hover {
  opacity:0;
}

.posterEffect1:hover {
  transform:scale(1.02,1.02);
}


/* the main table holder for the posters */
.table {
     width: 100%;
     max-width: 900px;
     border: 0px solid black;
     text-align:center; 
     margin-left:auto; 
     margin-right:auto; 
     border-spacing: 4px;
}

/* sets the body properties */
body {
    background-image:url('pic/lego.jpeg');
    background-color: #ffd700;
    text-align:center; 
    font-size: 25px;
}


/* the title attributes */ 
body{margin:0;padding:0}
#head {
    background-image:url('pic/lego1.jpeg');
    background-repeat:repeat;
    width: 100%;
}

/*the menu line div attributes */
body{margin:0;padding:0}  
#line {
    background-image:url('pic/line.jpeg');
    background-repeat:repeat;
    width: 100%;

}
```

Here is a demonstration https://jsfiddle.net/MalMan35/e9nebpoz/
my guess is that because it is in tr and td tags that somehow that is messing it up.I have tried sooooo many thing but to no avail. I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: This really is not a good use for tables. Tables should only be used for data, not layout.

Comment: @magnetwd While I 100% agree with you, some guidance on how to better layout the page would be helpful.

Comment: @DarrenS Yes please!

Answer (score 0):

It's because you you are using absolute positioning on the images which is causing them to stack on the relative div.

```
.posterEffect img {
      position:absolute; // <-- Remove this
      left:0;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
      transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

This will allow the images to flow normally. I am guessing you are doing this so you can fade in a new image to overlay it with opacity that has a blur effect on it.

With CSS3 you can actually create the blur effect with CSS! This eliminates the need to load multiple images in the browser and cleans up your code a bit.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter

CSS Blur Effect

```
.posterEffect img{
     width:300px;
     height: auto; //use auto heigh to maintain scaling
     -webkit-transition: filter 0.4s;
     -moz-transition: filter 0.4s;
     -o-transition: filter 0.4s;
     transition: filter 0.4s;
}
.posterEffect img:hover{
    filter: blur(10px)
}
```

Comment: Okay I learned how to blur images and such I while back but it was such a pain to get the text to go in the middle of the image. Maybe you could better show me how. Where I learned how to make the text go in the middle of the image didn't explain the reason behind the different things that made it work so that made it hard for me to adapt it to my website and my needs. Could you please teach me how to do it. :)

Comment: Sure but that information extends the scope of the original question you asked. You should try to create a new layout, and when you run into an issue, Post a NEW question.

Comment: Okay I'll get to it! Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I really didn't dig how to fix your issue –as i haven't used tables for this– but if you are redesigning your site, you should remake your layout. It's going to make future websites you build, a lot easier.

Using tables is **not the way** to go, never!. (only data)

I made you a [little jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/gujojo/edit?html,css,output) with some elements from your site. Hope you can get a clearer picture of how to build your layout with this.

There's still **a lot of things** to take care and tackle, but i guess it's a good starter.

If you need more help, i'll be glad to help you. :)

Comment: Um I never used tables before. Current design of my website. www.mem3500films.minksfamily.com

Comment: @MalMan35 Ok, but you are using them on this new design :P Tables are going to be really painful whenever you try to change something in the future, and responsiveness on mobile will be worse.

Take a look at [HTML5 Boilerplate](https://html5boilerplate.com/), download it and hack/play with it. Check the source code.  

If you have a bit of time and want to learn how to build a responsive website (which will make it easier to understand things for future coding) you should try this [How to Build a Responsive Website - Series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T6jKLsxbFg4)  

Keep on hacking! :)

Comment: I don't know of any other way to get it in a collage like I have it and yet it still be responsive. The way I have it is responsive. The table doesn't have any size values so it adjusts to the image. I just use the table to hold the images together like in a collage. Do know of a better way to position the image like I have them but without using a table?

Comment: @MalMan35 If you take a look at the jsbin i made, there are two 'pinterest-style' cards. With some `@media queries` ([info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)) you could have complete responsiveness. You may also want to learn more about `grid systems`.  I've learnt a lot checking [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)' s way of doing things. You can dig there :)  

[Bootstrap guide](http://www.taniarascia.com/what-is-bootstrap-and-how-do-i-use-it/)

[This short video will give you a bigger picture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X228ppg8CEI)

Comment: YAHHHOOO! I succeed in completely removing tables from my design! It took me several hours but it now looks exactly the way it did before but without using tables! Not only that the image resize with the window! I give you more details later!

Comment: that's awesome!! Congrats :) Let me know when it's done!

Comment: This is the way I made it work with out the table http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734514/how-can-i-easily-make-a-text-title-in-the-middle-of-an-image